# Convergence of Fourier series in $L^2$ space

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm learning about Fourier series, specifically $L^1$ and $L^2$ convergence, and need help with the following exercise:

> True or False (justify):
>
> $(1)$ The trigonometric series $2 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left(k\cos{kx} + {1 \over k}\sin{kt}\right)$ is the Fourier series of a $2\pi$-periodic function $f\in L^1([-\pi, \pi])$.
>
> $(2)$ The trigonometric series $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} {1 \over \log{n}} \cos{nx}$ is the Fourier series of a function $f\in L^2([-\pi, \pi])$.
>
> $(3)$ The trigonometric series $2 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left({2 \over \sqrt{k}}\cos{kt} + {1 \over k} \sin{kt}\right)$ is the Fourier series of a function $f\in L^2([-\pi, \pi])$.

Since I'm having difficulties with $(2)$ and $(3)$ I'm going to show my work for $(1)$.

$(1)$ By the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma we know that the Fourier coefficients of $f$ must tend to zero when $k$ approach infinity, i.e. $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k = \lim_{k \to \infty} b_k =0$. This is certainly true for $b_k = {1 \over k}$ but the limit for $a_k = k$ is clearly divergent as $k \to \infty$. Therefore, the proposition is **false**.

---

Is my work correct for $(1)$? I want to apply a similar argument for $(2)$ and $(3)$ but I can't apply the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma since we're looking at convergence in $L^2$.

Comment: (2) The Fourier coefficients are square summable iff $f\in L^2$. $\sum_{n =2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^2} = \infty$ tells you the series is *not* the Fourier series of $f\in L^2$. (3) is also not the Fourier series of an $L^2$ function because $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n})^2}=\infty$.

Comment: @TrialAndError Thank you for your explanation. These are consequences of Parseval's identity, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, these are consequences of Parseval's identity. If $f$ is Lebesgue measurable and integrable on $[0,2\pi]$, then $f \in L^2[0,2\pi]$ iff the Fourier coefficients are square-summable, i.e., in $\ell^2$.